# COM Port emulation in VMWare

Tags: vmware

I have an USB COM Port Emulation in my physical machine. I want to access this from my virtual machine (VMWare). How I can make my virtual machine detects that port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The USB rs232 interface is just so an usb device, as any other.

Give the USB device to the virtual machine:

1) In VMWare Workstation, you have the icons in the down right corner for that.

2) In VMWare ESXi server, you can add the new usb device from the vmware client (or vmware web client) by editing the virtual machine parameters.+